# Is there a sequence satisfying this condition?

Tags: combinatorics

So the condition would be that we have to transform the sequence $\{1,1,2,2,...,50,50\}$ into a sequence where there are $n$ elements between every two $n$... So between the 2 $1$'s there has to be $1$ element

Comment: You're talking about sequences, not sets.

Comment: Well but is there one?

Answer (score 2):

This is [Langford's problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LangfordsProblem.html).  The number of solutions is given in [OEIS A014552](http://oeis.org/A014552).  There are no solutions for $n\equiv 1,2 \pmod 4$, so no solution with $n=50$.  I found a solution $23421314$ for $4$ by hand then did a web search for that number.  A sketch of the proof that there are no solutions for $n \equiv 1,2 \pmod 4$ is on [this page](http://www.dialectrix.com/langford.html) under the heading Roy O. Davies finds key to the Solvability of 'n'